# ConTeXt: page large enough to contain a FLOWchart

Tags: context

How can I create a page which has the minimum size to contain the one FLOWchart defined in it?

I'm looking for something identical to `\startMPpage` but for FLOWchart

> \startMPpage produces a page a containing MetaPost graphic. The page
>   is just large enough to contain the graphic.

A minimum document using `\startMPage`:

```
\starttext
\startMPpage
fill fullcircle scaled 5cm withcolor red ;
\stopMPpage
\stoptext
```

this produces a cropped page containing only the circle.

The following document will produce a full A4 page with a flow-chart in it:

```
\usemodule[chart]
\starttext
\startFLOWchart [cells]
  \startFLOWcell
    \name {first}
    \location {1,1}
    \shape {singledocument}
    \text {not realy a document}
  \stopFLOWcell
\stopFLOWchart

\placefigure
   [here][]
   {}{\FLOWchart[cells]}
\stoptext
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For MetaPost content you can use the environment `MPpage`, as you mentioned.
For TeX content use the environment `TEXpage`. FLOWchars use MetaPost
internally, however, the code is TeX, so you need to use TEXpage.

Furthermore, you don't need a figure. A figure is *floating*, which means TeX
determines the position automatically, which is not what you want here. It
makes only sense for multi-page documents containing text paragraphs as well.
Here's a complete example.

```
\usemodule[chart]

\startFLOWchart [cells]
  \startFLOWcell
    \name {first}
    \location {1,1}
    \shape {singledocument}
    \text {not realy a document}
  \stopFLOWcell
\stopFLOWchart

\starttext
  \startTEXpage
    \FLOWchart[cells]
  \stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

FLOWcharts contain a margin by default. If you want to adjust for this margin
you can use the `offset` key, either with positive or negative values:

```
\startTEXpage [offset=2cm]
  \FLOWchart[cells]
\stopTEXpage

\startTEXpage [offset=-1cm]
  \FLOWchart[cells]
\stopTEXpage
```

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for: thank you very much.